# Java: Printer lookup from Linux for a printer in a Windows machine

Tags: java, windows, linux, lookup, printers

I'm having problems when trying to **directly** (without any dialog) print a PDF on a Java Web application (on a Websphere Application Server 6.1) and a Java program (both share some code which include this printing code) with a printer. The printer is on a Windows host, and the web application and the non web application are run on Linux.

I have read that it could be a permission problem, as I would be trying to print with a user in Linux that either doesn't exist on the printing system (Windows) or doesn't have persmissions.

The server and the Java application are run with user root, so I'm stuck here (if it's a permission problem) as I was told by the client that the user with permissions on the printing server is another one. I know the username that is allowed to print on that server.

I think it could do it if it's possible to associate Linux's root user with the user on Windows (which has permissions to print) through Samba. But I haven't been able to do it (I'm quite noob in Samba knowledge). Even if I could do this, I'm not sure that it would allow the code to lookup the printer in the Windows machine. I didn't find any method to autheticate or connecting to a server either.

For further information, I use the class `javax.print.PrintServiceLookup` in order to looking the printer up, that doesn't seem to have a method to allow me to authenticate on a server or something similar. This is the code:

```
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    /* Create an array of PrintServices */
    AttributeSet aset = new HashAttributeSet();
    aset.add(new PrinterName(pObjImpresora, null));
    aset.add(new RequestingUserName("user", null));

    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, aset);
    if (services.length > 0) {
        aObjLog.info("IMPRESORA SELECCIONADA: " + pObjImpresora);
        job.setPrintService(services[0]);
        PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1));
        JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, pObjJasperPrint);
        /* We set the selected service and pass it as a paramenter */
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE, services[0]);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, services[0].getAttributes());
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.exportReport();
    }
```

`pObjImpresora` is a `String` which has printer's name. I should have a way to reach the server and then the printer on it. I tried this name `"\\\\printserver\\MYPRINTER"`, where `printserver` is the Windows host name, and `MYPRINTER` is my printer  ;)

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?  I'm starting research to do something similar and came across a number of options, but don't know what works or what edge cases to consider when doing it.